# ADAL 3.2 alpha AcquireTokenAsync iOS does not dismiss sign in form

Tags: xamarin.forms, adal

I've been using the ADAL 3.x alpha versions with Xamarin.Forms on iOS for a couple of months now and had no problems with 3.0 and 3.1, however with 3.2 I get the problem that the sign in screen does not dismiss when you click the "Sign in" or "Cancel" buttons on the web page, only the iOS "Cancel" button in the navigation bar works, but this obviously cancels the sign in.
When I roll back to 3.1 and do the rename for the (I)PlatformParameters, the problem goes away and I can sign in again.
I have created a small sample application to illustrate the problem:
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=97da305fa5f403ab%216242

Comment: I tried your sample application, but it worked successfully for me. Do you have the latest version of Xamarin installed?

Comment: Yes, as far as I am aware: Xamarin 3.11.445, Xamarin.iOS 8.10.0.0 and I am testing on XCode Simulator 8.3.

Comment: What is the redirect uri that you are passing? We just found an issue with case sensitivity of the redirect uri which causes such behavior. If that is what you are observing, we are going to fix that soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally had some more time to work on this. It seems that the newer version of the ADAL component does not like captial letters in the redirect URI. The previous versions had no trouble with this, but apparently this one does. So using only lower case characters in the uri's solves the issue.